# What is this type of search called? Is it secondary/in page search?

Tags: website-design, search, usability-testing

[image]

The topmost search is global search.

In the image provided on top, I would like to know what is the second type of search called?  Is it called secondary or in page search? Does it have any technical word?

What will I call this one (image placed below for reference)? In this case, I've two search bar.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I usually refer to this as a *contextual* search, simply because that part of the page generally contains the current context of the user (see figure below). Thus, the search *should* search through this context.

[image]

Figure source: [Information Architecture for the World Wide Web: Designing Large-Scale Web Sites, 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596527349), a pretty solid reference on Information Architecture.

Comment: the image which you have added as a reference doesn't it represent an example for navigation? Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yeah, sorry - that was a bit unclear. I meant that a search _placed within_ the contextual navigation (like your example), is probably best referred to as a contextual search opposed to the global search that is placed within the global navigation. There are, however, no reference to this in the book. It seems like advocate _one_ search interface.

Comment: Got your point. I've attached one more image for reference. Let me know your thoughts on this.